# Conditionals and Loops reverseword what am I missing?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to get the desired outputs like here [Tests 1-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAy5x.jpg) and still prompt the user to input the tests using the Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in). My program says out of range. How should I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String word="";
    System.out.println("Enter a Word:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    word= scan.next();
    for (int j=word.length(); j>=0; j--) {
        System.out.println(word.substring(j-1, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `System.out.print()` to keep everything on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

```
new StringBuilder(scan.next()).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    for (int j=word.length(); j >=1; j--)
    {
    System.out.println(word.substring(j-1, j));
    }
```

> Explanation: In your for loop j should only decrement till j>=1.  When
>   j = 1 Because you do substring(j-1, j) = substring(0, 1)
>
> In your case, when j becomes 0, substring(j-1, j) = substring(-1, 0)
>
> Hence the exception, as string does not have -1 as an index.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to last iteration of loop when `j=0` in this case you are doing `word.substring(j-1, j)` ie `word.substring(-1, 0)` Giving you that error.

Instead change the loop to `j>=1`

```
String word = "";
System.out.println("Enter a Word:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
word = scan.next();
System.out.println();
for (int j = word.length(); j >= 1; j--) {
 System.out.print(word.substring(j - 1, j));
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Fu9tLm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of making a substring each time. Simple charAt(index) would do.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = scanner.next();
for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it :)